# Question about Arrow Diagrams of Relations, Example 1.3.3. - Epp - Discrete Mathematics

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The task says: "Let A = {1, 2, 3} and B = {1, 2, 3} and define relations S and T from A to B as follows:
For every (x, y) ∈ A*B,

(x, y) ∈ S means that x < y               S is a “less than” relation.

T = {(2, 1), (2, 5)}"

And then the solution shows the drawing of a circle with 1,2 and 3 and another circle to the right of it with 1, 3 and 5 with arrows indicating the relation of the smaller numbers on the left with the bigger numbers on the right, and this is titled "S-->", probably showing relation S.

How is there a 5 and no 2 in the second circle???

If (x,y) are elements of A*B, then the cartesian product is the set with the ordered pairs (1,1,), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3), and obviously then the set S is defined as the set in which we have those of the ordered pairs from A * B where x<y; where does the 5 come from and where is the 2?

Then the second drawing shows a circle with 1, 2 and 3 and another circle with 1,3 and 5, and arrows from 2 to 1 and 2 to 5). Again, where does the 5 come from and where is the 2 in the second circle, if A*B has no 5?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).